# Justifying that $B$ can always be represented as a curl of a vector field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, differential-geometry, vector-fields

I'm trying to justify a claim from [Feynman's 14th lecture](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_14.html#:%7E:text=Now%20the%20curl%20of%20B,curl%20of%20another%20vector%20field.),

> In electrostatics we saw that (because the curl of $E$ was always zero) it was possible to represent $E$ as the gradient of a scalar field ϕ. Now the curl of $B$ is not always zero, so it is not possible, in general, to represent it as a gradient. However, the divergence of $B$ is always zero, and this means that we can always represent $B$ as the curl of another vector field. For, as we saw in Section 2–7, the divergence of a curl is always zero. Thus we can always relate $B$ to a field we will call $A$ by:
>
> $$B = \nabla \times A.$$

How does divergence of $B$ being zero imply that it can always be written as a curl of another vector field?

---

### My attempt

I've tried of the justifying the claim my self using [Helmholtz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) and the only thing I could get is that $B$ can be split into two divergence free parts, one of which is a [Laplacian vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_vector_field).

> Helmholtz's theorem also known as the fundamental theorem of vector calculus, states that any sufficiently smooth, rapidly decaying vector field in three dimensions can be resolved into the sum of an irrotational (curl-free) vector field and a solenoidal (divergence-free) vector field.

Let use decompose the magnetic field by Helmholtz's theorem:

$$ B= B_{div free} + B_{curl free}$$

If we take divergence of both side:

$$ 0 = 0+ \nabla \cdot B_{curl free}$$

But, this would mean $B_{curl free}$ is actually a Laplacian vector field.

So, we can rewrite $B= B_{div free} + B_{laplacian}$ from this, how do we go to the fact that $B$ is necessarily equal to curl of some other vector field?

Comment: If $\nabla^2 f = 0$ and $f(x)=0$ on the boundary of your region on interest (for example, at infinity when you think about all space) then $f(x)\equiv 0 $

Comment: What's the name of the theorem which says this? @OfekGillon

Comment: it is a well known result when dealing with Laplace or Poisson equation, which leads to the uniqueness of solutions in many cases. I'm sure you'll find material about it. For example I found here in stack exchange this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1536965/ . But there is a lot of info online about this

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/594575/2451

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the field dies off at infinity and using the fact that harmonic function zero at boundary is zero in domain [(ref)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536965/using-greens-identity-to-show-that-a-harmonic-function-with-zero-boundary-value), we have:

$$ B= B_{div free}$$

Now, a divergence free vector field is necessarily a curl of another vector field [(see)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4073159/showing-that-a-divergence-free-vector-field-is-curl-of-a-vector-potential). And hence, we can write:

$$ B= \nabla \times A$$